# "abstinence" vs "abstention" - What's the difference?

Tags: meaning

How are these two words different?

• total abstinence from strong drink

• abstention from intoxicating drinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstinence from something refers to "intentionally avoiding something". Typically it is used for intoxicants, meat, and sex.

Abstention is a synonym of abstinence. However, this word is primarily used for abstaining from voting (such as during elections)